# Why integration bus connector is not fired?

Tags: kentico

I'm using Kentico MVC v12 with a fresh installation of DancingGoat(MVC) template.

I've 2 projects in my solution:

- CMSApp: the backoffice website
- DancingGoat: the ecommerce website

[image]

My connector is a C# class that is placed in a folder in CMSApp project.

The goal of my connector is to register to execute custom logic each time a user is created.

Here is my C# connector code:

```
public class CmsUserIntegrationConnector : BaseIntegrationConnector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the connector name.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Init()
    {
        // Initializes the connector name (must match the code name of the connector object in the system)
        // GetType().Name uses the name of the class as the ConnectorName
        ConnectorName = nameof(CmsUserIntegrationConnector);

        SubscribeToObjects(
            TaskProcessTypeEnum.AsyncSimple,
            PredefinedObjectType.USER,
            TaskTypeEnum.CreateObject);
    }


    public override IntegrationProcessResultEnum ProcessInternalTaskAsync(GeneralizedInfo infoObj, TranslationHelper translations, TaskTypeEnum taskType, TaskDataTypeEnum dataType, string siteName, out string errorMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            if (infoObj.TypeInfo.ObjectType == PredefinedObjectType.USER.ToString())
            {
                if (taskType == TaskTypeEnum.CreateObject)
                {
                    EventLogProvider.LogInformation(
                        nameof(CmsUserIntegrationConnector),
                        nameof(ProcessInternalTaskAsync),
                        "User created on SAP !!!!!");
                    UserInfo user = infoObj.MainObject as UserInfo;


                    // Consume SAP webservice and provider user info

                    // Save SAPId received from webservice in user custom field
                    using (CMSActionContext context = new CMSActionContext())
                    {
                        context.LogWebFarmTasks = false;
                        context.LogEvents = false;
                        context.LogExport = false;
                        context.LogIntegration = false;
                        context.LogSynchronization = false;
                        // code that creates/saves the object goes here

                        user.SetValue("SAPID", Guid.NewGuid()); // (new Random()).Next(0, 100)
                        UserInfoProvider.SetUserInfo(user);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLogProvider.LogException(
              nameof(CmsUserIntegrationConnector),
              nameof(ProcessInternalTaskAsync),
              ex);
            errorMessage = ex.Message;
            return IntegrationProcessResultEnum.Error;
        }

        errorMessage = null;
        return IntegrationProcessResultEnum.OK;
    }
}
```

What happens now:

- If I create a user in the user module of the backoffice my connector is fired
- If I create a user via the ecommerce website, nothing happens..

Should I create a library project, put the C# connector class in it and add it as reference in both websites, and maybe doing something more in the configuration ?

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you by advance !

Update:

I tested the solution proposed by Dražen Janjiček to use "IntegrationHelper.ProcessExternalTask" but it didn't work (more info here: https://docs.kentico.com/k12/integrating-3rd-party-systems/using-the-integration-bus/creating-integration-connectors/implementing-incoming-synchronization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on right track with separate library and referencing it to MVC site and administration. You are working with two applications and right now, code is registered just to one of those via CmsUserIntegrationConnector Init() event. With custom library, both applications will be able to load assembly and initialize connecter since assemblies are loaded per reference via AssemblyDiscoverable attribute.

Comment: Externalise the connector in a separate dll solved the issue, thank you !